# fitting COM-Poisson in R

Tags: r, regression, poisson-distribution, underdispersion

I have some crash data I did Poisson for that and the data was underdispersed.  I want to do COM-Poisson regression for my data. I see that every website suggest several packages for COM-Poisson and I've got confused.

Please help me to know what package I have to use to fit this model for my underdispersed data. And what is the code. If I have to define "nu" in my code how can I do that?
Yy data has dependent variable of crash and 9 independent variables like speed, curve, left turn ...